# Application crashes when orientation is changed

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, orientation

** EDIT **
I now changed everything to fragmenttransactions and I'm not using static fragments in xml files.

The problem I have now is when I start in landscape mode everything is fine. But if I turn the tablet to portrait and back its now reversed... I can see the same onCreate() method is called and it does exactly what it should do but it just reverse everything.

Do I need to remove the fragments before adding them again?

Comment: Did you try to call removeView() before setContentView

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see your comment.

No I have not. I should probably try it, do I need to remove both fragments? Or am I lost when I say that?

Comment: ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(myView.getParent());
vg.removeView(myView);      ----maybe this can help you?

Comment: actually just saw that someone posted as answer the same exact thing. I guess its the way to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove previous view first:

```
((ViewGroup)yourchildview.getParent()).removeView(yourchildview);
```

Comment: So I should add configChanges back again? how do I get my childview?
Thank you for taking your time to look at this problem.

Comment: I had a few problems but I think I sorted most of it out. Now I get another bug but in the end you helped me solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

That's wrong. Let `Android` restart your application. If you add the folder `values-land` and put inside it the layout for landscape, all will happens automagically

Comment: I am. But the problem is that I have these folders:
layout, layout-sw600dp-land, layout-sw600dp-port

in layout I'm using a viewpager for phones.
in land I'm showing the two fragments off and in portrait I want it to become like layout. But it crashes when it switches between viewpager somehow.

Comment: ok blackbelt now I went back to what you said. I got my layout under layout-sw600dp-port and -land. it all works fine, but as soon as I change fragment and then change orientation I get the problem I edited in before. Thank you for looking at my problem :)

Comment: Are you remove public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){....} after you use layout-port/layout-land? It should be removed to avoid errors...